# Observed frequencies of a drum versus mathematically predicted frequencies

Tags: experimental-physics, acoustics, differential-equations, home-experiment

I built a small circular drum in order to compare the actual resonant frequencies versus the resonant frequencies predicted by modeling it as a circular membrane obeying the wave equation with fixed boundaries.

The model is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane

I set a speaker next to the drum and proceeded to write down the frequencies it resonated at.

I got the following observed frequencies:

(0,1) : 101 Hz

(1,1) : 190 Hz

(2,1) : 265 Hz

(0,2) : 276 Hz

(1,2) : 362 Hz

Here the symbols (n,m) denote the vibrational mode of the drum head.

Now if you choose one of these frequencies, say (2,1): 265 Hz, you can then create a mathematical prediction for the other frequencies using the above model.

Specifically, by solving $\omega* \alpha_{2,1} = 265$ for $\omega$, where $\alpha_{2,1} = 5.13562$, you can then write down the following predicted frequencies

(0,1) : 124 Hz

(1,1) : 197 Hz

(2,1) : 265 Hz (this one was fitted)

(0,2) : 284 Hz

(1,2) : 362 Hz

There are some discrepancies between observed and predicted frequencies. My question is why is there such a big difference between the (0,1) observed of 101 Hz and the (0,1) predicted of 124 Hz.

What sort of effects are causing these errors as I get to lower frequencies?

This youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4ELxKKT5Rw&ab_channel=DanRussell
also has the same thing occur, where the higher frequencies tend to agree with the predicted frequencies, yet the lowest frequency is far off.

Edit:
Regarding the drum, it is essentially identical to the one in the video. It is a latex dental dam stretched over a round piece of PVC pipe. I am then holding the drum next to the speaker and waiting for the drum to vibrate to figure out the resonant frequencies. Then I hold a stroboscope up to it to determine the shape.

Comment: What's the geometry of the drum itself? Have you accounted for the mass of air that you're moving?

Comment: How would I account for the air?

Comment: To the next level of approximation, you have two coupled resonators, the drum and the pipe. The theory is complicated. Or, you can try different lengths of pipe, see what the effect is.

Comment: Did you determine the resonance frequency by peak picking the spectrum of a measurement? It might be insightful to look at the spectrum and neighbouring frequencies in more detail, since I would expect the signal energy in the spectrum of the experimental data to be more spread out. How long was the measurement? Did you use a FFT? What type of window function did you use? What was your sampling frequency?